# How to capture overlay and webcam together in Processing?

Tags: java, processing

I've written a simple code to use the webcam feature with an overlay, but when i try to capture pictures it's the webcam picture only, is there anyway i can combine the overlay and webcame picture together when saving?

```
import processing.video.*;

int w = 1280;
int h = 720;
int i = 0;
Capture camDevice;
PImage overlay;

void setup() {
  size(w, h);
  camDevice = new Capture(this, w, h);  
  camDevice.start();
}

void draw() {
  overlay = loadImage("overlay.png");
  if (camDevice.available() == true) {
    camDevice.read();
  }

  image(camDevice, 0, 0);
  image(overlay, 0, 0, width, height);
}

void keyPressed() {
  if ( key == 's' ) {
    if (i<300){
      i++;
    } else i = 1;
    //camDevice.save( "stillFrame"+i+".png" );
    saveFrame("Frame-"+i+".png"); //Found this in the library that does exactly what i wanted
  }
}
```

Comment: The call to `loadImage()` should be in `setup()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching & trying, i gave up, and instead found this neat feature that does exactly what i need:

```
saveFrame()
```

more: https://processing.org/reference/saveFrame_.html